# Approximate $F$ by a function of the type $f(t) = ae^{bt}$ by the least squares method

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

> Approximate $F$ by a function of the type $f(t) = ae^{bt}$ by the
>   least squares method
>
> F(t) - 132 65 31 17 8
>
> t   - ----1---2 -3--4 - 5

This is what my teacher did (sketches because I don't know all the logical steps that he did):
$$\min ||F(t)-f(t) || = \min_{a,b} \sum_{i=1}^5 (F(t_i)-ae^{bt_i})^2$$

$$F -ae^{bt}\implies \ln F - \ln ae^{bt} = \ln a + bt $$

$$\min\sum(\ln F(t_i)-\ln a + bt_i)^2$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    \langle 1,1\rangle       & \langle 1,t\rangle \\
    \langle t,1\rangle & \langle t,t\rangle 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
   \alpha      \\
    \beta
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
   5       & 15\\
   15 & 55
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
   \alpha      \\
    \beta
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \langle \ln F, 1\rangle   \\
    \langle \ln F,t\rangle  
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I think that that matrix of inner products came from this:

We're trying to find $\min ||F(t) - f(t)||$. This is the same as projecting $F(t)-f(t)$ onto the subspace generated by $f(t)$, so we should have:

$$\langle \ln F-\ln a - bt,1\rangle=0\\ \langle \ln F-\ln a - bt,t\rangle=0$$
which implies

$$\langle \ln F,1\rangle = \langle\ln a,1\rangle + \langle bt,1\rangle\\\langle \ln F,t\rangle = \langle\ln a,t\rangle + \langle bt,t\rangle$$

which is the same as

$$\langle \ln F,1\rangle = \ln a\langle 1,1\rangle + b\langle t,1\rangle\\\langle \ln F,t\rangle = \ln a\langle1,t\rangle + b\langle t,t\rangle$$
which is the system we have above.

**Now the question is: which inner product he used to get that matrix? I don't have idea on how to take inner product of those things.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In linear least squares, you are using the little 'el two' $l^2$ inner product since you have discrete data points.

$$<f,g> = \sum_{i=1}^{5} f_ig_i.$$